# Chern-Simons theory with only small gauge transformations

Tags: gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, chern-simons-theory

Usually when one derives the variation of the Chern-Simons action in 2+1 dimensions, one has a term that is proportional to the winding number. Then one argues that the coupling constant must be an integer for the whole term to be a multiple of $2 \pi$, so that the partition function is gauge invariant.

Can we instead just restrict the gauge transformations to small gauge transformations (zero winding number) and let the coupling constant be anything, or does any problem arise from this?

I'm especially interested in the $G=SU(N)$ case.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406939/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316013/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic, the linked questions explain why one requires $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but they do not discuss the possibility of restricting the allowed gauge transformations instead of quantizing the coupling constant. This is my question here.